# No IPv6 link-local address assigned to ethernet adapter, but is working on Wi-Fi

Tags: networking, 20.04, network-manager, ipv6

I have a fresh Ubuntu 20.04 install on a system with 2 interfaces - Ethernet (`enp2s0`) and Wi-Fi (`wlp3s0`).

On the `enp2s0` interface I set a static IPv4 address and `wlp3s0` is using DHCP for Internet access.

```
$ ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 6c:3c:8c:27:6c:47 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.100.222/24 brd 192.168.100.255 scope global noprefixroute enp2s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether bc:f4:d4:3e:8c:e7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.112/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp3s0
       valid_lft 64648sec preferred_lft 64648sec
    inet6 fe80::61d3:a84f:b1d9:84ed/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

The problem is, I need an IPv6 link-local address on the `enp2s0` interface, but it doesn't get any IPv6 address assigned, even though IPv6 is configured as "auto".

Tried setting IPv6 mode to "link-local", no difference.

```
$ sudo nmcli connection show enp2s0
connection.id:                          enp2s0
connection.uuid:                        34bae62f-1dea-4444-a526-208b929ac8bb
connection.stable-id:                   --
connection.type:                        802-3-ethernet
connection.interface-name:              enp2s0
connection.autoconnect:                 yes
connection.autoconnect-priority:        0
connection.autoconnect-retries:         -1 (default)
connection.multi-connect:               0 (default)
connection.auth-retries:                -1
connection.timestamp:                   1697313910
connection.read-only:                   no
connection.permissions:                 --
connection.zone:                        --
connection.master:                      --
connection.slave-type:                  --
connection.autoconnect-slaves:          -1 (default)
connection.secondaries:                 --
connection.gateway-ping-timeout:        0
connection.metered:                     unknown
connection.lldp:                        default
connection.mdns:                        -1 (default)
connection.llmnr:                       -1 (default)
connection.wait-device-timeout:         -1
802-3-ethernet.port:                    --
802-3-ethernet.speed:                   0
802-3-ethernet.duplex:                  --
802-3-ethernet.auto-negotiate:          no
802-3-ethernet.mac-address:             6C:3C:8C:27:6C:47
802-3-ethernet.cloned-mac-address:      --
802-3-ethernet.generate-mac-address-mask:--
802-3-ethernet.mac-address-blacklist:   --
802-3-ethernet.mtu:                     auto
802-3-ethernet.s390-subchannels:        --
802-3-ethernet.s390-nettype:            --
802-3-ethernet.s390-options:            --
802-3-ethernet.wake-on-lan:             default
802-3-ethernet.wake-on-lan-password:    --
ipv4.method:                            manual
ipv4.dns:                               --
ipv4.dns-search:                        --
ipv4.dns-options:                       --
ipv4.dns-priority:                      100
ipv4.addresses:                         192.168.100.222/24
ipv4.gateway:                           --
ipv4.routes:                            --
ipv4.route-metric:                      -1
ipv4.route-table:                       0 (unspec)
ipv4.routing-rules:                     --
ipv4.ignore-auto-routes:                no
ipv4.ignore-auto-dns:                   yes
ipv4.dhcp-client-id:                    --
ipv4.dhcp-iaid:                         --
ipv4.dhcp-timeout:                      0 (default)
ipv4.dhcp-send-hostname:                yes
ipv4.dhcp-hostname:                     --
ipv4.dhcp-fqdn:                         --
ipv4.dhcp-hostname-flags:               0x0 (none)
ipv4.never-default:                     no
ipv4.may-fail:                          yes
ipv4.dad-timeout:                       -1 (default)
ipv6.method:                            link-local
ipv6.dns:                               --
ipv6.dns-search:                        --
ipv6.dns-options:                       --
ipv6.dns-priority:                      100
ipv6.addresses:                         --
ipv6.gateway:                           --
ipv6.routes:                            --
ipv6.route-metric:                      -1
ipv6.route-table:                       0 (unspec)
ipv6.routing-rules:                     --
ipv6.ignore-auto-routes:                no
ipv6.ignore-auto-dns:                   no
ipv6.never-default:                     yes
ipv6.may-fail:                          yes
ipv6.ip6-privacy:                       -1 (unknown)
ipv6.addr-gen-mode:                     stable-privacy
ipv6.ra-timeout:                        0 (default)
ipv6.dhcp-duid:                         --
ipv6.dhcp-iaid:                         --
ipv6.dhcp-timeout:                      0 (default)
ipv6.dhcp-send-hostname:                yes
ipv6.dhcp-hostname:                     --
ipv6.dhcp-hostname-flags:               0x0 (none)
ipv6.token:                             --
proxy.method:                           none
proxy.browser-only:                     no
proxy.pac-url:                          --
proxy.pac-script:                       --
GENERAL.NAME:                           enp2s0
GENERAL.UUID:                           34bae62f-1dea-4444-a526-208b929ac8bb
GENERAL.DEVICES:                        enp2s0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       enp2s0
GENERAL.STATE:                          activated
GENERAL.DEFAULT:                        no
GENERAL.DEFAULT6:                       no
GENERAL.SPEC-OBJECT:                    --
GENERAL.VPN:                            no
GENERAL.DBUS-PATH:                      /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/554
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/5
GENERAL.ZONE:                           --
GENERAL.MASTER-PATH:                    --
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.100.222/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            --
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 192.168.100.0/24, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 100
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
```

What am I missing? How to get IPv6 working on `enp2s0`?